# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: , how do I fix this?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a button in pygame, which is meant to be part of my Snake game but I keep getting this error. I am not sure what I have done wrong.

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

GREEN = '#00FF00'
gameFont = pygame.font.SysFont('Courier', 32)

class button():
    def __init__(self , x, y, w, h, t_inp):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.t_inp = t_inp
        self.colour = GREEN
        self.text = gameFont.render(self.t_inp, True, self.colour)
        self.text_rect = self.text.get_rect(center=(self.x, self.y))

def draw(self):
    buttonRect = Rect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.rect.w, self.rect.h)

button1 = button('Start Game', 200, 40,(400,400))




window_size = (800,800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_size))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            #
            #       
        pygame.display.update()
```

if someone could help it would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: See what init expects and then see how you instantiate your `button`

Comment: `button` needs 5 arguments, you only gave it four: `button('Start Game', 200, 40,(400,400))` That's what the error is telling you. `(400,400)` is considered *one* value.

Comment: Thank you, can I write it like this (400),(400) so that I have two values

Comment: You can, but it doesn't make much sense for the string `'Start Game'` to be the value for the `x` parameter.

Comment: oh okay thank you, what would you suggest to write if you don't mind me asking. i am new to pygame

Answer (score 0):

The object `button1` is initialized with 4 params instead of 5 (`x, y, w, h, t_inp`)

Answer (score 0):

The problematic line is here:

```
button1 = button('Start Game', 200, 40,(400,400))
```

If we look at the `__init__` method for a `button`, we have this:

```
def __init__(self , x, y, w, h, t_inp):
```

The first parameter, `self`, refers to the object, and you ignore it when you instantiate a new object. Then there are five parameters you do need to provide.

However, you are only providing four. Note that `(400, 400)` is a single argument of the type `tuple`. It is made into a tuple by the parentheses. You either need to remove those or figure out what argument you are actually missing. (It's unclear to me if it's *supposed* to be a tuple - that is dependent on what the functions that value is sent to are expecting.)

Note that you have also made `window_size` a tuple, and also parenthesized it when passing it to `set_mode()`. This may also be incorrect, but unrevealed since you're errorring earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor requires 5 arguments (`x`, `y`, `w`, `h`, `t_inp`). (By the way, by convention, class names begin with a capital). Here are some valid calls:

```
Button(200, 40, 400, 400, "Start Game")
Button(200, 40, t_inp="Start Game", w=400, h=400)

dimensions = (400, 400)
# Button(200, 40, dimensions, "Start Game") is not valid
# you should use a star * to unpack the width and height:
Button(200, 40, *dimensions, "Start Game")

coordinates = (200, 40)
Button(*coordinates, *dimensions, "Start Game")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function that you defined:

```
class button():
def __init__(self , x, y, w, h, t_inp):
```

you mention 5 arguments but when calling the function, you only provide 4 arguments:

```
button1 = button('Start Game', 200, 40,(400,400))
```

You need to provide one more argument

Comment: @SakinaKhan Kindly upvote the answer and mark it as answer if it helped you so others can also benefit

Comment: i would like to but since i made my account only yesterday the website will not let me sorry